# Replace values in multiple columns based on another set of columns

Tags: r, compare, na

I want to remove values from multiple columns if they are greater than another set of columns.

Something similar that works for a single column (check.1) is `filter(if_any(before.1:before.3,~ check.1 < .x))`. This filters the rows whereby check.1 is less than any of the before columns.

However, I also have columns check.2, check.3, etc. and would only want to remove the row if all check columns are greater than any of the before columns (I can do this easily enough afterwards).

My main aim is to simply replace any check column value with NA if it is greater than any of the before column values in each row. More than happy to clarify as it's a bit of a strange question

Start:

| before.1 | before.2 | before.3 | check.1 | check.2 | check.3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34 | 23 | 33 | 35 | 14 | 46 |
| 56 | 24 | 24 | 45 | 63 | 14 |

Finish:

| before.1 | before.2 | before.3 | check.1 | check.2 | check.3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 34 | 23 | 33 | NA | 14 | NA |
| 56 | 24 | 24 | 45 | NA | 14 |

I feel like it may be something like:

```
mutate(across(check.1:check.3,~na_if(.x >before.1:before.3)))
```

but this doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

1. I think your "finish" is missing that `check.1` row 1 is greater than its `before.1` value, that should also be `NA` (?)
2. `na_if` is only going to replace with `NA` values that are equal, there's no inequality testing, we can shift to `if_else` with no difficulty.
3. We can't reference `before.1:before.3` in that way, we can use `cur_column()` to get the current column (e.g., `"check.1"`), change "check" to "before", then pull that column with `cur_data()[[..]]`.

```r
mutate(bef, 
  across(
    check.1:check.3,
    ~ if_else(.x > cur_data()[[sub("check", "before", cur_column())]], NA, .x)
  )
)
#   before.1 before.2 before.3 check.1 check.2 check.3
# 1       34       23       33      NA      14      NA
# 2       56       24       24      45      NA      14
```

Kinda makes you want an `across2(..)` function, just like `purrr::` has `map2` and `reduce2`. We can wrangle `map2` to work here, though I don't know that it's much better than above:

```r
bef %>%
  mutate(
    data.frame(purrr::map2(
      pick(check.1:check.3), pick(before.1:before.3),
      ~ if_else(.x > .y, NA, .x)))
  )
#   before.1 before.2 before.3 check.1 check.2 check.3
# 1       34       23       33      NA      14      NA
# 2       56       24       24      45      NA      14
```

---

Data

```r
bef <- structure(list(before.1 = c(34L, 56L), before.2 = 23:24, before.3 = c(33L, 24L), check.1 = c(35L, 45L), check.2 = c(14L, 63L), check.3 = c(46L, 14L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions

I can't get either to work in my case at the moment. perhaps my example wasn't great?

The columns all have completely different titles so the first example using sub() doesn't work for me.

The second example looks good but I have 5 before columns and 114 check columns so I get a map2 error whereby it can't recycle .x to meet .y - further made an issue in that the code needs to accept different numbers of columns each time it runs (I've managed this elsewhere with `mutate(across((match("Col_start",names(df))+1):(match("Col_finish",names(df))-1))`